# macOS: Is it possible to find out who is intercepting my outgoing (HTTP) communication?

Tags: networking, macos, security, http, trojan

**Quick question:**

Is there any way to find out who or what process is intercepting outgoing HTTP connections on macOS?

**Details:**

Environment: macOS Sierra

When trying to open pretty standard web pages (blogs, news portals) most of them got stuck on connection "pending" status. I discovered that then pending resources were often URLs pointing to CDN networks (such as Amazon AWS, Google, ...).

Tried in various browsers - with the same result:

- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox
- 'wget'   (yes, even wget..)

One of the wget results:

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/cc.silktide.com/cookieconsent.latest.min.js
--2017-02-28 21:08:51--
http://s3.amazonaws.com/cc.silktide.com/cookieconsent.latest.min.js
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com... 52.216.224.19
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com|52.216.224.19|:80... failed: Operation timed out.
```

After a reboot: the same problem.

A second (Windows) computer on the local network could access the same URL without any problem.

Reconnected the Mac from the local network through an iPhone's hotspot (through 3G cellular network, avoiding the local WiFi) and still timeout; although the same URL is working from the phone directly. This made me thing that the problem isn't in the local network but on the machine.

A conclusion might be that there is a software or trojan intercepting my outgoing HTTP connections that just failed at the moment. I'm not using an personal firewall or internet security scanner.

The problem has seemingly disappeared in a couple of hours.

Is there any chance to find out what was wrong before I completely reinstall the Mac?

Comment: Amazon's S3 had a major outage last night in Eastern US, but, affecting a lot of CDN content around the world.

Comment: Wow :o That would explain a lot. Do you think is it a reasonable explanation why it was working on the Windows machine (and the iPhone) that it could be either 1) served from cache or 2) from a different server as a failover?

Comment: Quite possible. I was using an online service last night that was affected - Second Life, a live 'interactive world' structure, where I work helpline. Some were crippled, some could work normally. There appeared to be no common ground as to who would be affected. I was not, my partner sitting 3 ft away from me couldn't get on at all.

Comment: That's sounds very similar to what happened to us. I guess it explains the situation. Thank you for your answer!